# Spotty wireless on Acer C7 with 13.04

Tags: wireless, drivers, ath9k, compat-wireless

My Acer came with the Atheros AR9462 and it's giving me problems. The ath9k nohwcrypt solution seems like it helped a little bit--but only delayed the inevitable dropping networks every few minutes, unable to connect, etc.

I've looked into compat-wireless but can't figure out how to get it installed and set up.

```
$ uname -r
3.4.0

$ sudo apt-get install linux-headers-generic
...
The following extra packages will be installed:
linux-headers-3.8.0-30 linux-headers-3.8.0-30-generic
```

Is there something weird going on with my Chrubuntu install (Ubuntu on Chromebook) that's making my kernel weird? Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

As a follow-up, for anyone that runs into this problem on the Acer C7 Chromebook:

Installing Ubuntu 13.04 fixed **ALL** of my wi-fi issues.

I wiped the partition and reinstalled Chrubuntu but with 13.04 and wi-fi works great now.

I'll also add that XFCE4 has made this little Chromebook screaming fast (given that it was $130). Everything works great--including bluetooth!